# XCode UI Testing -- Buttons do not exist unless they are off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm testing an app in which there are custom buttons on UITableViewCells, and I need to include the use of these buttons in order to access certain features that I need to test.

When I record a press of these buttons, I am presented with code for simply tapping on the TableViewCell -- resulting in undesired actions.

I added accessibility identifiers to my buttons in order to attempt to work around this problem, however, the buttons are not being detected in the app heirarchy unless they are off screen. If I expand a cell, pushing some of these buttons off the screen, and I print out the debug information, I am presented with this:

```
Other 0x155fcf080: traits: 8589934592, {{-4.0, 789.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}
   Button 0x155fcf800: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {21.0, 22.0}}, label: 'Down'
   StaticText 0x155fcff50: traits: 8589934656, {{0.0, 0.0}, {41.0, 23.0}}, label: 'Allergies'
   Button 0x155fd06a0: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {24.0, 24.0}}, identifier: 'new_allergy_button', label: 'add new icon'
Other 0x155fd0e90: traits: 8589934592, {{-4.0, 833.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}
   Button 0x155fd1610: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {21.0, 22.0}}, label: 'Down'
   StaticText 0x155fd1d60: traits: 8589934656, {{0.0, 0.0}, {41.0, 23.0}}, label: 'Results'
Other 0x155fd24d0: traits: 8589934592, {{-4.0, 877.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}
   Button 0x155fd2c50: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {21.0, 22.0}}, label: 'Down'
   StaticText 0x155fd33a0: traits: 8589934656, {{0.0, 0.0}, {41.0, 23.0}}, label: 'Documents'
   Button 0x155fd3af0: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {24.0, 24.0}}, identifier: 'new_document_button', label: 'add new icon'
```

Showing my buttons are indeed in the heirarchy -- (new_allergy_button and new_document_button.)

When I print out the debug information of the same screen, except without expanding a cell (leaving new allergy button on screen), I am instead presented with this:

```
Other 0x127034fc0: traits: 8589934592, {{-4.0, 478.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}
   Other 0x127035710: traits: 8590000128, {{-4.0, 478.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}, label: 'Allergies'
Other 0x127035e80: traits: 8589934592, {{-4.0, 522.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}
   Button 0x127036600: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {21.0, 22.0}}, label: 'Down'
   StaticText 0x127036d50: traits: 8589934656, {{0.0, 0.0}, {41.0, 23.0}}, label: 'Results'
Other 0x1270374c0: traits: 8589934592, {{-4.0, 566.0}, {328.0, 44.0}}
   Button 0x127037c40: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {21.0, 22.0}}, label: 'Down'
   StaticText 0x127038390: traits: 8589934656, {{0.0, 0.0}, {41.0, 23.0}}, label: 'Documents'
   Button 0x127038ae0: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {24.0, 24.0}}, identifier: 'new_document_button', label: 'add new icon'
```

As you can see, the button with identifier "new_allergy_button" is missing..

Furthermore, I tried implementing an XCTAssert to test if the button exists:

```
XCTAssert([app.buttons[@"new_allergy_button"] exists], @"new_allergy_button does not exist.");
```

and the test fails when the button is on screen, and passes when the button is off screen.

This is causing major issues because I cannot tap on the buttons for UITesting if they are not being detected.

What is the reason for this occurring? And how can I possibly fix this?

Comment: When you interact with the cell to make the button appear, or when you assert whether the button exists, so you get anything in the debug output about using a cached snapshot or view hierarchy?

Comment: Are your tableviewcells containers or accessible items in their own right? If I remember right, I ran into a similar problem where on-screen accessible objects do not permit deeper queries within the hierarchy, because accessible objects are not containers (e.g., accessible objects can never have accessible children).

Comment: @AaronSofaer They are accessible items (when tapped, they expand to reveal more items).

Comment: Interesting. Are they, or some other accessible object, the parent of the buttons? Is that "Other" in the hierarchy properly a container?

Comment: @AaronSofaer the "other" on the heirarchy are custom uitableviewcells -- how can I tell if they are properly a container?

Comment: Experiment: where you declare the custom uitableviewcells, set isAccessibilityElement to be false/no.